# show record on wicked_pdf on ruby on rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, wicked-pdf

So i wanted show on pdf file just selected record. Now i get all record, or just first one when i search for `localhost:3000/service_orders.pdf`. When click the button "print" when they just give error something link this.

```
ServiceOrdersController#show is missing a template for this request format and variant.
```

My file.pdf.erb :

```
<%  @service_order ||= ServiceOrder.find(params[:id]) do |service_order| %>
    <td> <%= service_order.number %> </td> ...
    %< end %>
```

My service orders controller :

```
     def index
        @service_orders = ServiceOrder::Collector.call(params: params.permit!.to_h)
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.json
          format.pdf {render :pdf => "service_orders/file",
          :template => '/file', formats: :html, encoding: 'utf8'}
        end
      end
    ...
    ...
   def show
     @service_order = ServiceOrder.find(params[:id])
   end
```

My link button is on show.html.erb

```
<%= link_to 'Print', service_order_path(@service_order, :format => :pdf),:format => :pdf,  class:"button-show "%>
```

And of course my mimi_types.rb file include  `Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf`

I been looking for internet, and closest thing was this. I hope someone was the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not specify format in `show` action so by default it tries to render `html` template. You have to add:

```rb
   def show
     @service_order = ServiceOrder.find(params[:id])
     respond_to do |format|
          format.html
          format.json
          format.pdf do 
            render pdf: "name_of_template",
            some other options
          end
        end
   end
```

And locate template for this action in `views/service_orders/show.pdf.erb`